# why background color not changing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am using bootsrap in my html .I want to change the background color of my div  when screen resolution change from large to medium or small .I added class but it not reflect when i change my screen resolution .Here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/6sSYngN0hn2tZZ1wDEML?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Basic Bootstrap Template</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Optional Bootstrap theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>
    <style>
.col-lg-12{
    height: 50px;
    background: red !important;

}

.col-md-12{
    height: 50px;
    background: yellow !important;

}
.col-xs-12{
    height: 50px;
    background: black !important;
}
.col-sm-12{
    height: 50px;
    background: blue !important;

}

</style>
<body>


<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
hi
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you try media query?

Comment: but I am using grid view of bootstap.Internally it is using media query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it wasn't working because you defined your CSS properties without **media-queries**. as all the classes were added to a common `DIV`, the CSS property with highest **specificity** was getting applied.

Below is the solution to make it work.

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .col-xs-12 {
    height: 50px;
    background: black !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-12 {
    height: 50px;
    background: blue !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-md-12 {
    height: 50px;
    background: yellow !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-lg-12 {
    height: 50px;
    background: red !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Basic Bootstrap Template</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Optional Bootstrap theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>

<body>


  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        hi
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please don't use bold text all over your answer.

Comment: thanx @MelanciaUK, will remember it next time :)

Comment: additional to @DeepakYadav 's answer, you can use !important to override to previous css on the same media query size.